# How to navigate? (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to navigate to other screen and i am using class component. When i save my input datas into MySQL i want to navigate to the screen that called 'Map' . I tried ways that i know but i couldn't navigate at the end.

I am trying to navigate from AAddBinScreen to MapScreen ( i have this screen called 'Map' ).

Here is my code of AABinScreen:

```
constructor() {
       super();

       this.state = {
           ...
       }
       this.goMap = this.goMap.bind();
       
   }

   pressAdd(){
       const check = this.saveData();
       if(check == true){
           Alert.alert("Kayıt başarıyla eklendi.")
           setTimeout(this.goMap(), 800);
       }        
   }

   goMap() {
       this.params.navigation.navigate('Map');
   }
```

And here is my button.

```
render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                     ...
                     ...
                    <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.disabled} 
                                      activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.Btn} 
                                      onPress={()=>this.pressAdd()}>
                        <Text style={styles.btnText}>EKLE</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
module.exports = AAddBinScreen;
```

And my app.js

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
    ...
    Map: {
        screen: MapScreen,
        navigationOptions:{
            headerShown:false
        }
    },
    ...
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
});

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Comment: Try passing props as a parameter to super in the constructor and then use this.props.navigation.navigate

Comment: Also, setTimeout requires a function as a parameter. So `setTimeout(() => goMap(), 1) || setTimeout(goMap, 1)`

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't do it. Can you give a little more detail? @NachoZullo

Comment: Yes, but i need you to copy the 3 entire files. And your package.json too

Comment: I couldn't copy here but i found a online text publisher for that: https://justpaste.it/67w7a  
@NachoZullo

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the `constructor` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        address_m: '',
        street: '',
        district: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
        info: '',
        lat: '',
        lon: '',
    }
    this.goMap = this.goMap.bind(this);

}
```

You could also change `goMap` to an arrow function and avoid binding `this`

```
goMap = () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Map');
```

And you must change the `pressAdd` function because you are calling `goMap()` inside the `setTimeout` and it will be execute without waiting for the delay. You need to pass the function and not call it.

```
setTimeout(this.goMap, 800);
```